# Is there a way to autofill the suggested variable/function in visual studio rather than jumping to into the block statement?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm having a problem with visual studio preferences when deciding between autofill and moving down into the code block.

For example, when typing an if statement, if I have a bool named bMoving, and I want the if statement to check if bMoving is true, I will start typing the if statement like..

"if(bMo" then intellisense will suggest "bMoving" to me.

Normally if I click tab in other areas of the code, it will autofill the variable bMoving. However, when clicking tab while typing within the () of the if statement, it moves into the code block.

Is there an option for this preference in visual studio community?

Answer (score 0):

Either press [tab] to pick the most likely suggestion, or [Ctrl]+[Space] then [space] after choosing an option is probably what you want

Comment: It seems like [Ctrl]+[Space] then [space] seems to work okay, but is there a way to not have to press it every single time I'm typing into an if statement? This solution still requires me to press those keybinds each and every time I want to use autofill rather than jump into the code block.